# Should files permissions be transferred across computers?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

I am not a linux guru or anything, but I just learned about file permissions a few days ago and I found something worrying (may be because I don't understand it well). So lets say I have a malicious script and run this command `sudo chmod +x malcious_script`. If I have understood correctly, I have now given this script an executable permission in my computer and that is fine as long us I know what I am doing, but lets say I upload this script to github and someone clones it to their machine. Should this script still have an executable permission? (from what I tried it have (I used ubuntu 14 (if that matters) to first write the script and give it permission. I then downloaded the script to another virtual machine and the script still had an executable permission.))

Comment: I don't know what's worrying about that. The problem is downloading and starting a malicious software, not the fact that the filesystem regards it as executable. Nothing prevents anyone from making it executable manually after downloading.

Comment: What you seem to be wondering is "*If I git clone somebody else's software, and then run it, can it do something bad?*" Yes, of course it can. Your Ubuntu system assumes that YOU, the human, have evaluated the source and found the source to be trustworthy. If you order your Ubuntu system to jump off a cliff, it will try to obey you.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly the only use for this different permissions (rwx) is when you have many users in the same computer, and you want to give these users and their groups different level of access? I asked these question because I thought permissions were one way of trying to make linux more secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, a few different things:

- To be pedantic, you haven't given the script executable permission, you've given your user permission to execute the script.  This sounds like the same thing but it is critically different.  The file is inert so it's the user that must take the action that would potentially matter here.
- As an easy way to kind of look at the overall situation: Linux filesystem permissions cease to exist outside of the filesystem that created it.  If you use this same script on a Windows machine, Windows will have no concept of what like "755" permissions meant on Linux.
- Finally, git basically drops all the Linux filesystem permissions with the exception of the execute bit.  Outside of the exception for the execute bit, files created by `git clone` have their permissions otherwise set by your [umask](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html).

EDIT: To Answer the other questions:

- File permissions do make Linux more secure.  For instance, your user should really only have write permissions to your home directory.  If you do something silly or run a virus, the only place that things can be written to (without something like a [privesc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation)) is your home directory.  Clean up is super easy at that point, just delete your home directory and start over.  File permissions are also useful when you have multiple users on the system to ensure that they aren't able to read/write each other's files unless granted that permission.
- Regarding where permissions are actually stored, that information is kept in the filesystem as file metadata.  As a silly analogy, files are like letters with an envelope.  Editors and whatnot look at the letter whereas permissions, filename, etc are on the envelope which is stored as filesystem metadata.  If you want to get into the details, some of this metadata is stored in the [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) and some is stored in the containing directory entry.  When you transfer a file, only the data (the letter) is transferred and the metadata (the envelope) is discarded unless some other mechanism is in place to save the metadata (e.g. tar file, git as previously described, etc).

Comment: Thank you so much, can you also read my last comment above and say something about it

Comment: and one more quick questions, how does the system know what permissions have been given to a file. I mean when I open the file with a text editor all I see is the script but the computer seems to know the permissions too, even when the permissions weren't issued at that computer. (for instance when someonce clones as you told me the excute permissions still stick so basically my question how does the computer nkow that this file has the x permission)

Comment: Edited my answer to include your additional questions.

Comment: ok, thank you very much

Comment: Does file permission remain valid if the file is not transferred, but is exposed directly to another computer? For example, plugging the USB disk / hard disk into another computer.